# ZOE ERROR (from /usr/lib/snap/snap): error opening parameter file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, electron, snapcraft

I package  electron app on ubuntu 14.04 LTS using `snapcraft`.I build it by refering this [link](http://www.linuxuk.org/post/20160518_snapping_electron_based_applications_simplenote/).Package was build successfully but when i install the package using following command

```
 sudo snap install springbok_1.0.1_i386.snap
```

it shows the following error message

```
 ZOE ERROR (from /usr/lib/snap/snap): error opening parameter file
```

Here is my `snapcraft.yaml`

```
name: springbok
version: 1.0.1
summary: The simplest way to keep notes.
description: The simplest way to keep notes. Light, clean, and free.
vendor: Ajatus software <pitabas.prathal@ajatus.co.in>
icon: icon.png
apps:
  springbok:
  command: wrapper
  plugs: [unity7, opengl, network]
parts:
  springbok:
  plugin: copy
  stage-packages:
    - libnss3
    - fontconfig-config
    - gnome-themes-standard
files:
  springbok: springbok
  wrapper: usr/bin/wrapper
  icudtl.dat: icudtl.dat
  snapshot_blob.bin: snapshot_blob.bin
  natives_blob.bin: natives_blob.bin
  resources*: resources
  libnode.so: usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnode.so
  libffmpeg.so: usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffmpeg.so
```

here is my `wrapper`

```
 export FONTCONFIG_PATH=$SNAP/etc/fonts
 export FONTCONFIG_FILE=$SNAP/etc/fonts/fonts.conf
 export XDG_DATA_HOME=$SNAP/usr/share
 export           LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$SNAP_LIBRARY_PATH:$SNAP/springbok:$SNAP/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/

exec "$SNAP/springbok" "$@"
```

Comment: The given link is not found (error 404)